# why $(\pi ,4] \in \sigma ({\mathcal C})$? given ${\mathcal C}:=\big \{(a,b]:\, a,b\in {\mathbb Q}\cap [0,10]\big \}, \Omega :=[0,10]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given $${\mathcal C}:=\big \{(a,b]:\, a,b\in {\mathbb Q}\cap [0,10]\big \}$$

$$\Omega :=[0,10]$$

why $(\pi ,4] \in \sigma ({\mathcal C})$? I thought the $a,b$ can only be rational number and the complement and union of rational number intervals are still bounded by rational number right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take any decreasing sequence $a_n$ of rational numbers such that $a_n \to \pi$, then $$
(\pi,4] = \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}} (a_n, 4]
$$ Since $(\pi,4]$ is a countable union of sets in $C$, it belongs to $\sigma(C)$.

A proof that such a sequence indeed exists can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Sequence_Decreasing_to_Real_Number)

Comment: I see. So, it is possible to find interval bounded by any real numbers that are in [0, 10] in $\sigma(C)$

Comment: Any *open* interval, yes. Any open interval $(r_1, r_2)$ can be written as a countable union of intervals $(a_n, b_n]$ where $a_n$ decreases to $r_1$ and $b_n$ increases to $r_2$.